# Getting error: "column does not exist" in Postgres function

Tags: postgresql

Error:

```
{   
    "code": "42703",
    "details": null,
    "hint": null,
    "message": "column "service" does not exist"
}
```

I was writing a Postgres function (with help of ChatGpt, since I am new to supabase).

The goal of that function is to return all the services and their properties.

I created this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_services_connected_data()
RETURNS SETOF services_connected_response AS $$
DECLARE
  _workspace_id BIGINT := ((current_setting('request.jwt.claims'::text, TRUE))::JSON ->> 'workspace_id')::BIGINT;
  results services_connected_response[];
  services_connected_row services_connected_response;
BEGIN
  SELECT ARRAY[
    ('github', COALESCE(service_github.auto_invite, false), services_connected.github IS NOT NULL),
    ('zoom', COALESCE(service_zoom.auto_invite, false), services_connected.zoom IS NOT NULL),
    ('jira', COALESCE(service_jira.auto_invite, false), services_connected.jira IS NOT NULL),
    ('docusign', COALESCE(service_docusign.auto_invite, false), services_connected.docusign IS NOT NULL),
    ('asana', COALESCE(service_asana.auto_invite, false), services_connected.asana IS NOT NULL)
  ]
  INTO results
  FROM services_connected
  LEFT JOIN service_github ON services_connected.github = service_github.id
  LEFT JOIN service_jira ON services_connected.jira = service_jira.id
  LEFT JOIN service_zoom ON services_connected.zoom = service_zoom.id
  LEFT JOIN service_asana ON services_connected.asana = service_asana.id
  LEFT JOIN service_docusign ON services_connected.docusign = service_docusign.id
  WHERE services_connected.workspace_id = _workspace_id;
  -- This would give array of all the services which have workspace id in their tables (`services_xyz`)


-- This is for those which does not have value, so we would iterate  over it put auto invite and connected as false ---
  FOR services_connected_row IN
    SELECT unnest(ARRAY['github', 'zoom', 'jira', 'docusign', 'asana']) AS service
    WHERE service NOT IN (
      SELECT unnest(array_agg(service))
      FROM unnest(results) AS t(service_name, auto_invite, connected)
    ) 
  LOOP
  results := array_append(results, ARRAY[
    (services_connected_row.service_name, false, false)
  ]);
END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I have a table `service_connected` which looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."services_connected" 
(
    "id" bigint generated by default as identity not null,
    "created_at" timestamp with time zone default now(),
    "updated_at" timestamp with time zone default now(),
    "workspace_id" bigint not null,
    "google" bigint not null,
    "github" bigint,
    "jira" bigint,
    "zoom" bigint,
    "notion" text,
    "docusign" bigint,
    "asana" bigint
);
```

Here all the services are actually foreign key to the tables `service_github`etc and each table would've properties like `auto_invite`, `workspace_id`. If service_connected for say asana does not have any value (or foreign key), it means service_asana for that workspace does not exist

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example, the actual error, what you have tried to fix.

Comment: The problem is here; `... SELECT unnest(ARRAY['github', 'zoom', 'jira', 'docusign', 'asana']) AS service WHERE service ...`.  You can't use the column alias in the `WHERE` clause. You might try: `SELECT t.service from unnest(ARRAY['github', 'zoom', 'jira', 'docusign', 'asana']) AS t(service) WHERE t.service NOT IN ...`

Answer (score 0):

The exception is coming from this part of the code:

```
    SELECT unnest(ARRAY['github', 'zoom', 'jira', 'docusign', 'asana']) AS service
    WHERE service NOT IN (
      SELECT unnest(array_agg(service))
      FROM unnest(results) AS t(service_name, auto_invite, connected)
    )
```

The first issue is that `service` isn't a defined column at the time it's referenced in the `WHERE` clause. There are also issues with the subquery that checks to see if the service is in `results`. The following should correct those issues:

```
    SELECT s.service
    FROM UNNEST(ARRAY ['github', 'zoom', 'jira', 'docusign', 'asana']) AS s(service)
    WHERE service NOT IN (
      SELECT t.service_name
      FROM UNNEST(results) AS t(service_name, auto_invite, connected))
```

This video, [Secret To Optimizing SQL Queries - Understand The SQL Execution Order](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BHwzDmr6d7s&pp=ygUoc3FsIG9yZGVyIG9mIGV2YWx1YXRpb24gaW4gc3FsIHN0YXRlbWVudA%3D%3D), might prove useful.